# Override method with an empty one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

Is there a best practice to *emptify* a method in Ruby ?

I.e. in a subclass, if I want to override a method with nothing, is there another syntax than this :

```
class A
  def XX
    [..do something..]
  end
end

class B < A
  def XX
    # Do Nothing
  end
end
```

I would like to know if there is a keyword like...

```
class B < A
  void_method :XX
end
```

...because its clearer for code maintenance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't, and it would actually be more keystrokes than

```
def XX; end
```

However you could easily add such a method

```
class A
  def self.void_method name
    define_method(name) {}
  end
end
```

Or obviously you could add this to object if you are going to be using it in more places.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question what you want. If you want it to return no method error, then do this:

```
class B < A
  undef_method :XX
end
```

If you want it to return `nil`, then do this:

```
class B < A
  def XX *args, &pr; end
end
```

If you want it to return the receiver, then do this:

```
class B < A
  def XX *args, &pr; self end
end
```